# Failed to compile HTTP-Live-Video-Stream-Segmenter-and-Distributor

Tags: ubuntu, http-live-streaming

I am running on Ubuntu 11.10 with intention to compile [HTTP Live Video Stream Segment and Distrbutor](https://github.com/carsonmcdonald/HTTP-Live-Video-Stream-Segmenter-and-Distributor/).

By following instruction from [here](https://github.com/carsonmcdonald/HTTP-Live-Video-Stream-Segmenter-and-Distributor/wiki/Install-on-Ubuntu-10.10), I manage to setup FFMpeg accordingly. But run into tihs error when I tried to configure it.

gcc -v -Wall -g live_segmenter.c -o live_segmenter \
    -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lvorbis -ltheora\
    -lbz2 -lm -lz -lfaac -lmp3lame \
    -I/tmp/old_ffmpeg/include \
    -L/tmp/old_ffmpeg/lib

This following is the error message:

```
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=gcc
    COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/lto-wrapper
    Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
    Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,go --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
    Thread model: posix
    gcc version 4.6.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-Wall' '-g' '-o' 'live_segmenter' '-I' '/tmp/old_ffmpeg/include' '-L/tmp/old_ffmpeg/lib' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/cc1 -quiet -v -I /tmp/old_ffmpeg/include -imultilib . -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu live_segmenter.c -quiet -dumpbase live_segmenter.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase live_segmenter -g -Wall -version -fstack-protector -o /tmp/ccJ5ih1S.s
    GNU C (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) version 4.6.1 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.6.1, GMP version 5.0.1, MPFR version 3.0.1-p3, MPC version 0.9
    GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
    ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
    ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
    #include "..." search starts here:
    #include <...> search starts here:
     /tmp/old_ffmpeg/include
     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/include
     /usr/local/include
     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/include-fixed
     /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
     /usr/include
    End of search list.
    GNU C (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) version 4.6.1 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.6.1, GMP version 5.0.1, MPFR version 3.0.1-p3, MPC version 0.9
    GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
    Compiler executable checksum: 5dede901e38d49932d3155c3e888bca1
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-Wall' '-g' '-o' 'live_segmenter' '-I' '/tmp/old_ffmpeg/include' '-L/tmp/old_ffmpeg/lib' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
     as --64 -o /tmp/ccFEK6Gy.o /tmp/ccJ5ih1S.s
    COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
    LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-Wall' '-g' '-o' 'live_segmenter' '-I' '/tmp/old_ffmpeg/include' '-L/tmp/old_ffmpeg/lib' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/collect2 --build-id --no-add-needed --as-needed --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -z relro -o live_segmenter /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/crtbegin.o -L/tmp/old_ffmpeg/lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../.. /tmp/ccFEK6Gy.o -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lvorbis -ltheora -lbz2 -lm -lz -lfaac -lmp3lame -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
    /tmp/old_ffmpeg/lib/libavcodec.a(vaapi.o): In function `commit_slices':
    /home/tony/Desktop/ffmpeg-export-2009-12-01/libavcodec/vaapi.c:97: undefined reference to `vaCreateBuffer'
    /home/tony/Desktop/ffmpeg-export-2009-12-01/libavcodec/vaapi.c:106: undefined reference to `vaCreateBuffer'
    /tmp/old_ffmpeg/lib/libavcodec.a(vaapi.o): In function `alloc_buffer':
    /home/tony/Desktop/ffmpeg-export-2009-12-01/libavcodec/vaapi.c:125: undefined reference to `vaCreateBuffer'
    /home/tony/Desktop/ffmpeg-export-2009-12-01/libavcodec/vaapi.c:127: undefined reference to `vaMapBuffer'
    /home/tony/Desktop/ffmpeg-export-2009-12-01/libavcodec/vaapi.c:125: undefined reference to `vaCreateBuffer'
    /home/tony/Desktop/ffmpeg-export-2009-12-01/libavcodec/vaapi.c:127: undefined reference to `vaMapBuffer'
    /home/tony/Desktop/ffmpeg-export-2009-12-01/libavcodec/vaapi.c:125: undefined reference to `vaCreateBuffer'
    /home/tony/Desktop/ffmpeg-export-2009-12-01/libavcodec/vaapi.c:127: undefined reference to `vaMapBuffer'
    /tmp/old_ffmpeg/lib/libavcodec.a(vaapi.o): In function `destroy_buffers':
    /home/tony/Desktop/ffmpeg-export-2009-12-01/libavcodec/vaapi.c:37: undefined reference to `vaDestroyBuffer'
    /home/tony/Desktop/ffmpeg-export-2009-12-01/libavcodec/vaapi.c:37: undefined reference to `vaDestroyBuffer'
    /home/tony/Desktop/ffmpeg-export-2009-12-01/libavcodec/vaapi.c:37: undefined reference to `vaDestroyBuffer'
    /home/tony/Desktop/ffmpeg-export-2009-12-01/libavcodec/vaapi.c:37: undefined reference to `vaDestroyBuffer'
    /tmp/old_ffmpeg/lib/libavcodec.a(vaapi.o): In function `render_picture':
    /home/tony/Desktop/ffmpeg-export-2009-12-01/libavcodec/vaapi.c:48: undefined reference to `vaUnmapBuffer'
    /home/tony/Desktop/ffmpeg-export-2009-12-01/libavcodec/vaapi.c:61: undefined reference to `vaBeginPicture'
    /home/tony/Desktop/ffmpeg-export-2009-12-01/libavcodec/vaapi.c:65: undefined reference to `vaRenderPicture'
    /home/tony/Desktop/ffmpeg-export-2009-12-01/libavcodec/vaapi.c:69: undefined reference to `vaRenderPicture'
    /home/tony/Desktop/ffmpeg-export-2009-12-01/libavcodec/vaapi.c:74: undefined reference to `vaEndPicture'
    /home/tony/Desktop/ffmpeg-export-2009-12-01/libavcodec/vaapi.c:52: undefined reference to `vaUnmapBuffer'
    /home/tony/Desktop/ffmpeg-export-2009-12-01/libavcodec/vaapi.c:57: undefined reference to `vaUnmapBuffer'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Looks like some libraries missing, but I have no clue of what it is.

**How to solved this - Updated**

Just add -lva will do

gcc -v -Wall -g live_segmenter.c -o live_segmenter \
    -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lvorbis -ltheora\
    -lbz2 -lm -lz -lfaac -lmp3lame -lva\
    -I/tmp/old_ffmpeg/include \
    -L/tmp/old_ffmpeg/lib

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing libva, and you also don't need it. You can add --disable-vaapi to the ffmpeg configure. Otherwise, you'll need to add -lva to your LDFLAGS.

Comment: Thanks! apparently adding -lva into the command works, no idea how you trace that out. P/S. I have libva-dev installed for my machine.

Comment: @TonyMocha You just got to find which library contains the missing symbols. You can use nm to look through .so files, but google usually is quicker. What's interesting is that a lot of the libraries you link with aren't actually going to be used by the segmenter and are only there because of the options ffmpeg is compiled with. libva is just one of many.